# how to write my mongodb query in springboot reactive mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb, reactive-mongo-java

well below is my implementation

```
   db.services_performed.aggregate([{$match:{status:{$in: 
   ["INVOICING","outbound","accepted","PENDING APPROVAL"]}}},{$group:{_id:{date:{$dateToString: 
   {format:"%Y-%m-%d",date:"$created_on"}}},invoicing:{$sum:{$cond:[{$eq: 
   ["$status","INVOICING"]},1,0]}},outnound:{$sum:{$cond:[{$eq: 
   ["$status","outbound"]},1,0]}},accepted:{$sum:{$cond:[{$eq: 
   ["$status","PENDING APPROVAL"]},1,0]}}}}])
```

how can i convert my query into reactive springboot code
please help out with

Answer (score 0):

Create agregation query using mongo aggregation api:

```java
private Aggregation aggregationQuery() {
    Criteria statusCriteria = Criteria.where("status").in("INVOICING", "outbound", "accepted", "PENDING APPROVAL");
    MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(statusCriteria);

    ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project()
            .and(DateOperators.DateToString.dateOf("created_on").toString("%Y-%m-%d"))
                .as("date")
            .and(ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("status").is("INVOICING"))
                    .then(1)
                    .otherwise(0))
                .as("invoicing")
            .and(ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("status").is("outbound"))
                    .then(1)
                    .otherwise(0))
                .as("outbound")
            .and(ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("status").is("PENDING APPROVAL"))
                    .then(1)
                    .otherwise(0))
                .as("pendingApproval");

    GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group("date")
            .sum("invoicing").as("invoicing")
            .sum("outbound").as("outbound")
            .sum("pendingApproval").as("pendingApproval");

    return Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperation, projectionOperation, groupOperation);
}
```

Define your result class:

```java
@Data
public class ServicePerformedSummary {
    private String date;
    private int invoicing;
    private int outbound;
    private int pendingApproval;
}
```

Then autowire `ReactiveMongoTemplate` which is used to perform queries:

```java
@Autowired
private ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate;
```

And then you method to call mongo template with desired aggregation:

```java
public Flux<ServicePerformedSummary> getSummary() {
    return reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregationQuery(), "services_performed", ServicePerformedSummary.class);
}
```

at least it will give you an idea how to achieve what you want